# How to select particular region and scrape all the Jobs from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, web-scraping

I am trying to web **scrape** all the Jobs from a Job portal by selecting a particular country.

I am sorry to affix a picture but the intent to show you how the page looks like.

[image]

**What i tried:**

Below is what i tried but i;m not getting anything just started learning web scraping ..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


job_url = 'https://wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/careers/'
out_req = requests.get(job_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(out_req.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
   print(link.get('href'))
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's **scrape** *not* **scrap**. **scrap** - discard or remove from service.

Comment: @baduker, appreciate for correcting and teaching about `scrap` vs `scrape`, however i have corrected the typo. linguistically , I'm not a native English speaking person, please excuse my brevity.

Comment: Dear you can achieve that using selenium web driver.I can share basic code with you if you want to check it out. Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi, thnx for the kind help.

Answer (score 2):

Try selenium library, Search based on attributes & After search results **scrape** using beautiful soup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
#browser exposes an executable file
#Through Selenium test we will invoke the executable file which will then #invoke actual browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
# to maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()
#get method to launch the URL
driver.get("Website")
#to refresh the browser
driver.refresh()
# identifying the checkboxes with type attribute in a list
chk =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")
# len method is used to get the size of that list
print(len(chk))
# get_attribute method is get the value attribute
for i in chk:
if i.get_attribute("value") == "United states of America":
i.click()
#to close the browser
driver.close()
#############################
#Beautiful soup code here
#############################
```

Comment: @ Bhargav, thanks for the code i will try to check on it.

Comment: It's scrape not scrap. To scrap is to throw away, like rubbish